# With terraform set to create_before_destroy can I get it to remove a resource it on failure?

Tags: terraform

I create new AWS instances with `create_before_destroy` set. So these things are created before destroying the original resource. However sometimes provisioning fails, which then causes an unused resource to exist on AWS that has to be manually removed.

Since these are effectively temporary resources until they are replacing the existing infrastructure, is there some way of throwing the failed instance away automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but they are removed on the next success.